# How to support VRF in Netflow Collector?

Tags: python, cidr, netflow

I am somehow able to analyze netflow packet using my own netflow collector (build in python). It works for certain ip and CIDR(Classless Inter Domain routing), definitely not overlapping. What is the best way to support VRF(Virtual Routing and Forwarding) in netflow? I guess there is no any metadata in netflow packet for distinguishing either its VRF or not.

Comment: VRF aware Netflow is available in IOS starting with 12.4(11)T. What's your IOS version?

Comment: You can add vrf input name collection by adding `collect routing vrf input` to your flow-record. Not sure on top of my head how it will arrive in a packed, but I suppose some sort of `tcpdump` can help determining that.